# Parsing log lines using awk

Tags: parsing, sed, awk, logging

I have to parse some information out of big log file lines.
Its something like

```
abc.log:2012-03-03 11:12:12,457 ABC[123.RPH.-101] XYZ: Query=get_data @a=0,@b=1 Rows=10Time=100
```

There are many log lines like above in the logfiles. I need to extract information like
          datetime i.e. 2012-03-03 11:12:12,457
       job details i.e. 123.RPH.-101
      Query i.e.   get_data    (no parameters)
     Rows i.e. 10
     Time i.e. 100

So output should look like

```
2012-03-03 11:12:12,457|123|-101|get_data|10|100
```

I have tried various permutation computations with awk but not getting it right.

Comment: I just hope `Rows=10Time=100` was originally intended to be `Rows=10 Time=100`.

Comment: is "abc.log:" in the log file or is that grep output?

Answer (score 1):

Well, this is really horrible, but since `sed` is in the tags and there are no answers yet...

```
sed -e 's/[^0-9]*//' -re 's/[^ ]*\[([^.]*)\.[^.]*\.([^]]*)\]/| \1 | \2/' -e 's/[^ ]* Query=/| /' -e 's/ [^ ]* Rows=/ | /' -e 's/Time=/ | /' my_logfile
```

Answer (score 1):

TXR:

```
@(collect :vars ())
@file:@year-@mon-@day @hh:@mm:@ss,@ms @jobname[@job1.RPH.@job2] @queryname: Query=@query @params Rows=@{rows /[0-9]+/}Time=@time
@(output)
@year-@mon-@day @hh-@mm-@ss,@ms|@job1|@job2|@query|@rows|@time
@(end)
@(end)
```

Run:

```
$ txr data.txr data.log
2012-03-03 11-12-12,457|123|-101|get_data|10|100
```

Here is one way to make the program assert that every line in the log file must match the pattern. First, do not allow gaps in the collection. This means that nonmatching material cannot be skipped to just look for the lines which match:

```
@(collect :gap 0 :vars ())
```

Secondly, at the end of the script we add this:

```
@(eof)
```

This specifies a match on the end of file. If the `@(collect)` bails early because of a nonmatching line (due to the `:gap 0` constraint), the `@(eof)` will fail and so the script will terminate with a failed status.

In this type of task, field splitting regex hacks will backfire because they can blindly produce incorrect results for some subset of the input being processed. If the input contains a vast number of lines, there is no easy way to check for mistakes. It's best to have a very specific match that is likely to reject anything which doesn't resemble the examples on which the pattern is based.

Comment: This tool/language looks really interesting. Thanks for posting this.

Comment: Note that `Rows=10Time=100` is handled as specified in the question. That is an excellent example of a situation where we are justified to reach for a regex.

Answer (score 1):

My solution in gawk: it uses gawk extension to match.

You didn't give specification of file format, so you may have to adjust the regexes.

Script invocation:
`gawk -v OFS='|' -f script.awk`

```
{
match($0, /[0-9]+-[0-9]+-[0-9]+ [0-9]+:[0-9]+:[0-9]+,[0-9]+/)
date_time = substr($0, RSTART, RLENGTH)

match($0, /\[([0-9]+).RPH.(-?[0-9]+)\]/, matches)
job_detail_1 = matches[1]
job_detail_2 = matches[2]

match($0, /Query=(\w+)/, matches)
query = matches[1]

match($0, /Rows=([0-9]+)/, matches)
rows = matches[1]

match($0, /Time=([0-9]+)/, matches)
time = matches[1]

print date_time, job_detail_1, job_detail_2, query,rows, time
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another, less fancy, AWK solution (but works in mawk too):

```awk
BEGIN { OFS="|" }

{
    i = match($3, /\[[^]]+\]/)
    job = substr($3, i + 1, RLENGTH - 2)
    split($5, X, "=")
    query = X[2]
    split($7, X, "=")
    rows = X[2]
    split($8, X, "=")
    time= X[2]

    print $1 " " $2, job, query, rows, time
}
```

Nothe that this assumes the `Rows=10` and `Time=100` strings are separated by space, that is, there was a typo in the question example.

Answer (score 0):

Just need the right field separators

```
awk -F '[][ =.]' -v OFS='|' '{print $1 " " $2, $4, $6, $10, $15, $17}'
```

I'm assuming the "abc.log:" is not actually in the log file.