# Log analysis script in shell

Tags: shell

I'm a newbie in scripting and I need your help. I have a log file, that I'm cleaned out. Looks like this (Time, duration(in millisec), action):

```
2012-04-28 00:00:00;277.406; 
2012-04-28 00:00:00;299.680; 
2012-04-28 00:00:00;282.338; 
2012-02-28 00:00:00;272.241;
```

I need to make a script that use the duration data and count the action.

Comment: [What have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)? And what is the question?

Comment: Look at Awk Tutorial (http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html) and this SO question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10047817/parsing-log-lines-using-awk).

Comment: Thanks! Awk was my first idea, but now that all. I'm stuck.

Comment: @tomtom please post the code you've tried in Awk and what the error is and it may be possible to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First - you need to make it easier to parse the different fields. A simple way is to change a semicolon to a space using

```
tr ";" " " <logfile|awkscript
```

Second, you need to create a table of low and high values. I'm using an associative array whose index is the name of the column. I do this in the BEGIN section.

You need to count when a value is within the low and high values. I do this in the  middle section.

In the END section, I print out the values. I use 2 similar printf format strings to make sure the headers and values line up nicely:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
BEGIN {
    low["<1ms"]=0;high["<1ms"]=1
    low["1-10ms"]=1;high["1-10ms"]=10
    low["10-100ms"]=10;high["10-100ms"]=100
    low["100-500ms"]=100;high["100-500ms"]=500
    low[">500ms"]=500;high[">500ms"]=1000000000
}
{
# Middle section - for each line
duration=$3

for (i in high) {
    if ((duration > low[i]) && (duration <= high[i]) ) {
#       printf("duration: %d, low: %s,high: %s\n", duration, low[i], high[i]);
        total+=duration # total duration
        bin[i]++ # store a count into different bins
        count++ # total number of measurements
    }
}
}
END {
average=total/count
FMT="%-10s %10s %10s %10s %10s %10s\n"
NFMT="%-10.3f %10s %10s %10s %10s %10s\n"
printf(FMT,"AVG", "<1ms", "1-10ms", "10-100ms", "100-500ms", "500+ms")
printf(NFMT,average, bin["<1ms"], bin["1-10ms"], bin["10-100ms"], bin["100-500m\
s"], bin["500+ms"])

}
```

When I run this with your data, I get

```
AVG              <1ms     1-10ms   10-100ms  100-500ms     500+ms

282.916                                              4
```